# How to block upload adult or nude image?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem to uploading the image.I have to validate the image in which adult or nude  image is not upload.

Comment: Open image => See if it is NSFW => Do not upload.

Comment: Impossible. At least not with a script, i cant imagine the algorithm for that. You have to take a look at them yourself.

Comment: It's a terribly hard problem. Some libraries do that detection but they're not very reliable. You should probably ask your users to not upload nude images.

Comment: Im sure there are software that can do this, I just doubt they are free.

Comment: You can use this http://www.9lessons.info/2014/01/block-uploads-of-adult-or-nude-images.html

Comment: There is http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/nudejs/, which is based (apparently) on several papers on the subject. JS is a poor place to locate such an implementation though (you'd want to verify it on the server), but I'm not aware of any PHP libraries that do it.

Comment: @Matt If it can run in the browser, it can probably be ported to nodejs.

Comment: @dystroy: It uses HTMLCanvas etc to process the image, so I think it'll be a struggle.

Comment: This has been hold by Zword, hjpotter92, Rikesh, kapa, user2864740 but why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can  use online services like the [WebPurify Image Moderation Service](http://www.webpurify.com/image-moderation). or try nudity detection service [at Github](http://github.com/FreebieStock/PHP-Image-Pornographic-Content-Detection) or use [Googles' Nudity detection service.](https://code.google.com/p/nudetech/)

Comment: Note: this service is *man*-powered, still somethings a human is better at .. and it also costs *per image*.

Answer (score 3):

At this point in history the task of reviewing images needs to be done by humans, as photos are infinitely variable in content (and software is not that smart).

Depending on your website, you are better off with a *peer-review* system. That way you offload the small amount of work, per-image, onto your users.

Basically do not display new images until they have been reviewed by another user and offer some form of minor reward for reviewing images (fictional point systems, like SO, seem to work well) :)

You will also want to keep a reliability score for reviewers, so that if they pass invalid images, that are later reported as violations, they lose the ability to confirm more images.

Comment: A review/correction system is definitely still required. Even detecting "nudity" isn't sufficient (although maybe it could "auto flag"): "There are many such genres of porn. People in rubber suits. People in teddy-bear suits. Drawings of anthropomorphic animals having sex. Drawings of giants and giantesses having sex with normal-sized people. Photos of people contorting, stretching, piercing or entangling themselves in technically amazing but, to most viewers, deeply distasteful ways. The list goes on." (From http://www.dansdata.com/pornsweeper.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one for nude:

PORNsweeper

http://www.dansdata.com/pornsweeper.htm

Comment: That's a nice article and a good read; it gives as many reasons why *not* use use PORNsweeper and what inherent problems an automated system still has. (The article is not by the publisher, Content Technologies, but rather a review of the product.)

Comment: "PORNsweeper seems to have some ability to distinguish pictures of people from pictures of things that aren't people, as long as the pictures are in colour. It is less successful at distinguishing dirty pictures of people from clean ones .. this is a technical curiosity, not a useful piece of software."